# Electorate badge not properly calculated

Tags: support, badges

I have more than 600 votes (957) and more than 25% of them on questions. Still I'm missing the electrolux badge.

Phira mentioned in another thread, that he or she is missing this badge too.

Is there an explanation, or shall we take some action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cast at least 600 votes *on questions*. This is often misunderstood as "take 600 separate questions and vote on anything there, including answers", which is not the case. You have to vote on the question proper. Up or down.

As of the time of this writing, you have voted on 284 questions. That's 316 more to go.

Phira has voted on 262 questions. That's 338 more to go.

The meta Meta has [this handy table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/135907):

```
┌───────────┬─────────┬───────┬───────┬─────────────────────┐  
│        Your votes           | Ratio | Electorate awarded? │  
│ Questions │ Answers │ Total │  Q/A  │                     │  
├───────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────┤  
│       600 │    2400 │  3000 │   20% │   No; ratio too low │  
│       201 │     401 │   602 │  ~33% │ No; < 600 questions │  
│       599 │       0 │   599 │  100% │ No; < 600 questions │  
│       600 │       0 │   600 │  100% │                 Yes │  
│       500 │     500 │  1000 │   50% │ No; < 600 questions │  
│       650 │     650 │  1300 │   50% │                 Yes │  
└───────────┴─────────┴───────┴───────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see clearly, now ...

Comment: Reg, is it possible to see this stats for one's own votes or are moderators the only one who do have access to this information?

Comment: @Em1: go to your profile ([meta](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/users/1224/em1) or [main](http://german.stackexchange.com/users/1224/em1)) and look for the section "Votes Cast" in the lower right corner. That info is visible to anyone. You don't even have to be logged in.

Answer (score 2):

The badge description is a bit ambiguous. You have to vote on 600 *questions*.

Answer (score 1):

For [Electorate](https://german.stackexchange.com/badges/44/electorate) badge you need to cast votes on 600 **questions**, and more than 25% of votes are on questions. In you case of a total of 957 votes you have voted on questions 284 times only.